# call a python class method recursively

Tags: python, class, recursion, methods

I have a dictionary looking like this:

```
d ={'key1':{'key2':{'key11':{'key12':'value 13'}}},'key3':[{'key4':'value2', 'key5': 'value3'}]}
```

I want to get the value for 'key12' so I can do this:

```
d.get('key1').get('key2').get('key11').get('key12')
```

and  it will return this:

```
'value 13'
```

if I had a list like this:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key11', 'key12']
```

how could I call the `get` recursively over the above list to return the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key11', 'key12']
>>> reduce(dict.get, keys, d)
#or, reduce(lambda x,y:x.get(y), keys, d)
'value 13'
```

In python 3.8+ you can use the `initial` key in [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(accumulate(keys, dict.get, initial=d))[-1]
'value 13'
```

I would still prefer `functools.reduce`, even though [`Guido doesn't`](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Answer (score 0):

```py
d ={'key1':{'key2':{'key11':{'key12':'value 13'}}},'key3':[{'key4':'value2', 'key5': 'value3'}]}
ans = d.get('key1').get('key2').get('key11').get('key12')
print(ans)

key_list = ['key1', 'key2', 'key11', 'key12']
for key in key_list:
    d = d[key]

print(d)
```

Output:

```
value 13
value 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function which gets the dictionary and the list and returns the requested value:

```
def func(a, b):
    for key in b:
        a = a.get(key)
        if a is None:
            raise ValueError('There is no such key as ' + str(key))
    return a
```

Usage:

```
a = {'key1':{'key2':{'key11':{'key12':'value 13'}}},'key3':[{'key4':'value2', 'key5': 'value3'}]}
b = ['key1', 'key2', 'key11', 'key12']

print(func(a, b))
```

Output:

```
value 13
```